# Query outside of the transaction scope - Oracle

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

Is it possible to have insert statement outside of the scope of a transaction in a Stored Proc?
So there is a stored proc that writes some inserts, as part of a transaction
The reason for this is to write to Audit table and keep the audit records even if the stored proc fails or gets an exception

clarification, sorry if it was not clear, I am writing multiple audits for each action of the procedure so I can keep track what it did and what failed.  not just a single Audit when there is an exception...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sampleProc
IS
BEGIN

  start a transaction
      INSERT to table 1
      write to audit table about insert 1
      INSERT to table 2
      write to audit table about insert 2
      INSERT to table 3
      write to audit table about insert 3
      INSERT to table 4
      write to audit table about insert 4

     if there is an exception - rollback except audit 
     all ok? commit.

END;
/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is an option to perform actions in a separate transaction running simulteneously with your main one. See detail [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/static.htm#LNPLS00609)

Example:

```
create table logs(creation_date date default sysdate, msg varchar2(4000));

create or replace procedure log_proc(sMessage varchar2)
is
  pragma autonomous_transaction;
begin
  insert into logs(msg)
  values(sMessage);
  commit; -- don't forget to commit in this separate transaction
end;
/

begin
  log_proc('some message');
  rollback;
end;
/

select * from logs
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're after is `PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION`, which kicks off the module using it in a separate session.

Your code would be something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sample_proc
AS
  procedure audit_insert (<params>)
  is
    pragma autonomous_transaction;
  begin
    <log details>
    commit;
  end audit_insert;
BEGIN
  <INSERT to table 1>;
  audit_insert(...);

  <INSERT to table 2>;
  audit_insert(...);

  ...

EXCEPTION
  when others then
    rollback;
    raise;
END sample_proc;
/
```

Doing it like this would mean your audit details would be saved regardless of whether the calling code succeeds or fails.

N.B. I've created the `audit_insert` as a sub procedure of `sample_proc`. You would do better to have the code as individual procedures inside a package, rather than as one or more procedures.